# How to record a webpage with a gif in it using phantomJS

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, phantomjs, screenshot

I am trying to record a webpage which contains a gif using phantomJS. but on the output the video is very fast , please see the below gif

[The original gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG1nf.gif)

[The output video](https://media.giphy.com/media/26gmgOOb6VWQxNvuU/giphy.gif)

But the video i received plays very faster than the gif , is there any solution ?

PhantonJS code used

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1600, height: 900 };

page.open('http://192.168.2.4/index.html', function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var frame = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      page.render('Desktop/frames/dragon'+(frame++)+'.png', { format: "png" });
        if(frame > 150) {
        phantom.exit();
      }
    }, 1/25);
  }, 666);
});
```

the code will produce pngs and i will make the png as a video using ffmpeg.

Comment: What is wrong with the gif its amazing

Comment: @Tomm Please check the updated question

Comment: i am pretty sure they have a js,jquery whatever doesnt matter to slow done the frames, animations or whatever but i am 100% sure they have a function to slow those frames down

Comment: also can you link me the website

Comment: Hi @Tomm. I have used a local site , it doenst have anything , just a image tag with this gif

Comment: Another question then. Why are you trying to copy your own gif for own use??????

Comment: No , I am trying to create a tool that records a whole webpage , but what if the webpage contains a gif and the gif will be overspeed , it doesnt look good

Comment: Why are you trying to record a webpage?

Comment: @Tomm : Dude , too much questions , do you have a way to solved this?

Comment: I am trying to ask questions to make clear what I am trying to help you with. Cause recording a webpage can be done much and much more efficiently by using a screen recorder, does the same thing since you want a video

Comment: oh sorry , I have already used phantom js to record svg animations , i need to record gif now , Thats the reason i am opting for phantom js , else i would have prefereed somethin else, also being phantomjs a headless browser i can use it from cmd prompt

Comment: Maybe just use ffmpeg? PhantomJS is not really suitable for this task, creating png taskes a lot of time and it may just fall behind the animation.